# How to Reduce sidebarPanel Text Size in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

How would I reduce the text size and `selectInput` box size in my `Shiny` application?

Right now, I have four `selectInput` boxes and corresponding titles and they are pretty large.  I am looking to include up to 16 of them, but with a reduced size.  I've included a sample `ui.R` from the `Shiny` tutorial.  Thanks for your help!

Update: I updated the following code with the `tags$style` line.  This made the text smaller.  Now, I'm not sure how to make the selectInput box smaller.

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("censusVis"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("Create demographic maps with 
        information from the 2010 US Census."),
      tags$style(type='text/css', ".selectize-input { font-size: 10px; line-height: 10px;} .selectize-dropdown { font-size: 10px; line-height: 10px; }")
      selectInput("var", 
        label = "Choose a variable to display",
        choices = c("Percent White", "Percent Black",
          "Percent Hispanic", "Percent Asian"),
        selected = "Percent White"),

      sliderInput("range", 
        label = "Range of interest:",
        min = 0, max = 100, value = c(0, 100))
    ),

    mainPanel(
      textOutput("text1")
    )
  )
))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To reduce the font size, just add a bit of CSS to the document's header, targeting elements of class `"selectize-input"` and `"selectize-dropdown"`.  (Those affect, respectively, the font size shown in the selection bar and in its dropdown menu.)

To reduce the control's width, you can wrap it in a `fluidRow()` and allocate it some fraction of the 12 columns that the row contains.

Here's a fully reproducible example, which you can run by just copy and pasting into R:

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
        tags$head(tags$style(HTML("
        .selectize-input, .selectize-dropdown {
          font-size: 75%;
        }
        "))),    
        titlePanel("censusVis"),
        sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(
                helpText("Create demographic maps with
        information from the 2010 US Census."),    
                fluidRow(column(6,
                       selectInput("var",
                            label = "Choose a variable to display",
                            choices = c("Percent White", "Percent Black",
                                "Percent Hispanic", "Percent Asian"),
                            selected = "Percent White")
                )),
                sliderInput("range",
                            label = "Range of interest:",
                            min = 0, max = 100, value = c(0, 100))
                ),
            mainPanel(textOutput("text1"))
        )
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {}
)
```